# Помогите сделать парсер

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер, selenium

Хочу сделать бота, который будет получать агентства и сумму. Сначала он должен нажать кнопку и потом найти и получить эти данные.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://itdashboard.gov/')
    btn_elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn')
    btn_elem.click()
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/a/span[1]')
    print(title.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Однако он не находит даже по `xpath`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот сайт - https://itdashboard.gov/
Нужно нажать на кнопку 'dive in' и потом записывать названия департаментов.

Comment: Там вроде можно скриншоты делать. Мне в своё время помогло делать скриншоты и смотреть, что в браузере происходит вообще. Может там совсем не то показывает, что вы думаете.